# Can't return the list I want

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that works fine but instead of printing the results one after another, I want to append them to a list and return the list instead. I tried everything that I can think of but failed. Please help.

```
def calc_averages():

    allprices = [ ['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '',''],\
              ['','','' ,1.2 ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '', ''],\
              ['','','' ,1.2, '' ,1.8 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '', '', ''],\
              ['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.2 , '', '', '', ''],\
              ['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.1 ,1.2 ,1.4 ,1.8 ,1.9 ,2.2] ]

    averages = []
    for lst in range(0,12):
        counter = 0
        total = 0
        for item in allprices:
            if item[lst] != '':
                total = total + item[lst]
                counter = counter + 1
        if counter == 0:
            print('')
        else:
            print(total/counter)
```

I want to return the averages list after I append the values into it but returns as an empty list.

Comment: You should make sure the indentation in your code is correct or it's impossible to debug.

Comment: It does not return anything actually. You need to explicitly return a value. Else `None` is returned

Comment: "i tried everything I can think of"? You say you want to append them to a list and return that instead -- did you try appending to a list and returning that? I don't see any appending or returning in your function...

Comment: I tried to append but didn't posted it. It didn't work anyway

Comment: I knew that I have seen this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539493/my-code-works-for-a-single-list-but-not-for-a-nested-list-i-need-to-improve-it

Comment: I am new to programming and trying my best to solve this. Is that a crime? Sorry if you are offended but I am just looking for help not criticism. I thought this forum was very friendly

Comment: It doesn't return an empty list; it returns `None`. How is this question different from your previous one, and why did the answer you accepted not work?

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing with a less efficient way before and it didn't work in the end so I felt like asking again with my new code and got it now. Thank you all for everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not append to averages or return it at all

```
def calc_averages():

    allprices = [['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '',''],
              ['','','' ,1.2 ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '', ''],
              ['','','' ,1.2, '' ,1.8 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '', '', ''],
              ['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.2 , '', '', '', ''],
              ['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.1 ,1.2 ,1.4 ,1.8 ,1.9 ,2.2]]


    averages = []
    for outer in allprices:
        counter = 0
        total = 0
        for item in outer:
            if item != '':
                total += item
                counter += 1
        if counter == 0:
            print('')
        else:
            averages.append(total/counter)
    return averages

print(calc_averages())
```

Output

```
[1.3199999999999998, 1.3, 1.35, 1.35, 1.5750000000000002]
```

Comment: It only returned 1 item in averages list. There should be 9.

Comment: Your average calculation wasn't right, also you don't need to iterate over `range(0, 12)`, since you know your list is nested you can iterate twice over it, and there should be five results not 9 (You have five nested lists)

Comment: Well i am trying to calculate the average of nth price in each list so the calculation is actually for 4th values in each list which is (1.2 + 1.2)/2 since the first, fourth and fifth lists' 4th element is empty strings it doesn't count them. So my average calculation was right and I got it all working now, the calculation and returning the averages list. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just append the values to the list `averages`:

```
import statistics

def calc_averages():
    allprices = [['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '', ''],
           ['','','' ,1.2 ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '', ''],
           ['','','' ,1.2, '' ,1.8 ,1.3 ,1.1 , '', '', '', ''],
           ['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.2 ,1.2 , '', '', '', ''],
           ['','','', '' ,1.0 ,2.0 ,1.1 ,1.2 ,1.4 ,1.8 ,1.9 ,2.2]]
    averages = []
    for prices in zip(*allprices):
        try:
            averages.append(statistics.mean(p for p in prices if p!=''))
        except statistics.StatisticsError:
            averages.append('')
    return averages
```